# timestamp variable in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

I am getting below data in in bash script variable exp_dt:

```
exho $exp_dt
Jun  5 08:25:42 2023 GMT
```

need help to convert it into format like "05-Jun-2023" and days remaining from current date i.e.
64 days.

expected output

```
echo $new_var
05-Jun-2023|64 days
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
# your date
exp_dt="Jun  5 08:25:42 2023 GMT"

# actual day of year
b=$(date "+%-j")

# day of year of your date
c=$(date -d "$exp_dt" "+%-j")

# diffence of days
new_var=$((c-b))

# your solution
echo $(date -d "$exp_dt" "+%d-%m-%Y") "| $new_var days"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ts='Jun  5 08:25:42 2023 GMT'

echo "${ts}"

d=$(date -d "${ts}" +%d-%b-%Y)
sec=$(date -d "${ts}" +%s)
now=$(date +%s)
diff=$(expr $sec - $now)

days=$(expr $diff / 86400 )
new_var="$d|$days days"

echo $new_var
```

by running:

```
penguin:~$ sh d.sh 
Jun  5 08:25:42 2023 GMT
05-Jun-2023|64 days
penguin:~$
```